# IllegalArgumentException when using FXML

Tags: tornadofx

I've been following along the TornadoFX guide for using FXML (https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/wiki/FXML), but am getting a error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FXML not found for class ui.view.BoardView
```

Here's my BoardView.kt view:

```
class BoardView : View() {
    override val root: BorderPane by fxml()
    val hello: Label by fxid()

    init {
        hello.text = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

And here's the FXML file (in the same package, ui.view)
*

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="20" right="20" bottom="20" left="20" />
    </padding>
    <center>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10">
            <Label fx:id="hello">
                <font>
                    <Font size="20"/>
                </font>
            </Label>
        </HBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Here's the full stack trace if it helps:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FXML not found for class ui.view.BoardView
    at tornadofx.UIComponent$fxml$1.<init>(Component.kt:360)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.fxml(Component.kt:353)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.fxml$default(Component.kt:353)
    at ui.view.BoardView.<init>(BoardView.kt:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:238)
    at tornadofx.App.start(App.kt:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried giving arguments to fxml(), from "BoardView" to "BoardView.fxml" to moving the fxml file into src/main/resources. I couldn't see anything obvious looking at the Component.kt source file.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Have you tried typing TornadoFX into google or youtube? lots of examples out there.

Comment: Have you set BoardView.fxml to have controller class the BoardView class?I see no root in the fxml,not controller so i assume no.Have a look on that. :)

Comment: @GoXR3Plus In TornadoFX there is no need to supply the **fx:controller** parameter in the fxml file. The controller is dynamically assigned by the framework when it loads the fxml. This is inversed from plain JavaFX, where the FXMLLoader will instantiate the controller. Here the controller is instantiated first, and then the FXML is loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer first: Put the file in **src/main/resources/ui/view/BoardView.fxml** and don't supply a path parameter to the **fxml()** call.

If you are using Maven, it will not copy fxml files in **src/main/java** to the target directory by default, so even if you have the fxml file in the same package it will not be available unless you instruct Maven to copy resources with .fxml extension.

I recommend that you put it in **src/main/resources** instead, but remember that it also has to be in the same package there, so the correct path would be **src/main/resources/ui/view/BoardView.fxml**.

Alternatively, if you put it directly in **src/main/resources** you must add this path parameter to the fxml delegate:

```
override val root : BorderPane by fxml("/BoardView.fxml")
```

Note the **/** prefix to make it look in the root of the classpath.

A good tip would be to compile the project and look in the output folder (**target** by default for Maven projects) and check that the fxml file is in the location you expect.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have to keep that last tip in mind, got it working thanks to you though!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to join us on the Slack channel as well: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/messages/tornadofx/